# Name for a simple generalization of an exponentially distributed random variable

Tags: terminology, exponential-distribution

An exponentially distributed random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ has a simple survival function:
$S(k) := \Pr (X>k) = \exp(-k/\mu)$ for $k$ and $\mu$ non-negative.
Consider generalizing to 
$S(k) := \Pr (X>k) = \left(1 + c (\exp(k/\mu)-1)\right)^{-1}$ for $c>0$.
This is a valid survival function of a non-negative random variable $X$ which reduces to the exponential survival function when $c=1$.
This has to have been studied, but I can't find it.
Does anyone know the name of this generalized exponential random variable?